# How to call procedure from Spring Batch itemwritter and i need capture out put params data from procedute to call one more procedure

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-batch

I have one item writer in spring batch application to call a stored procedure with 4 input params and two output params. Now I am calling procedure to provide 4 input params data and it is executing fine but I need to capture output params of data. Again I need to call one procedure bypassing these two params of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch does not provide an item writer that calls a stored procedure. So you need to write a custom writer that does it and handle the output parameter as needed.

Comment: Yes, I have done by writing a custom item writer. Thanks for replay

Comment: How to create SpringBatch meta tables in another schema. I have created two different data sources one for item reader and another one(primary) for ItemWriter. i am giving database username as x and i am accessing another username y it is inside x. Coming to spring boot and batch properties file I am giving username as x. When i am running the application spring batch trying to pointing to x and it creating tables inside x only instead of creating inside y user. here y having business tables and pkg bla bla...